# vagrant update 1.8.1 to 1.8.5

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have installed vagrant 1.8.1 in fedora 24, this version not support for virtuvalbox 5.1, System throw this error:

```
    No usable default provider could be found for your system.

    Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
    "providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
    environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

    The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
    is available for free on all major platforms.

    If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
    is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
    why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
    `vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
    error message for that particular provider.
```

I eared vagrant 1.8.5 support for virtual box 5.1. so I need to update vagrant 1.8.1 to vagrant 1.8.5 (not download [Here](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html))

Suggest me how to do this  in fedora 24.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use Vagrant on Fedora (`dnf install vagrant`) and get this error message when trying to use it (`No usable default provider could be found`), try setting it in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

For fedora, you can download the rpm at https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.8.5/vagrant_1.8.5_x86_64.rpm and install the rpm.

Comment: I dont want to download new one , I need to update existing one. Any way is there. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: to update you need to download the latest version and install the rpm, vagrant will install on the same location so you won't loose any previous config

Comment: yes, "I won't loose any previous config", But, If I download New One my datapack(internet) take some extra data so, I prepared to update existing one. Is there any to update it?

Comment: not really - or at least not supported for sure. Potentialy if you had installed vagrant 1.8.5 somewhere else you could diff the install file from vagrant 1.8.1 and then only update the new gem etc ; but not supported for sure and maybe not really convenient

Comment: So, Only option to Download new one and install it  right . Thanks for your  support